# Untrusted Data in Vue w/ vuex

Tags: javascript, xss, vuejs3, owasp

currently learning vue3 with vuex.

Lets assume my vuex store is populated with data from some API.
Since the API is an external data source, it should be considered **untrusted**.

Let's also assume the following component:

In SomeComponent.vue:

```
<template>
 <a :href="'mailto:' + email">{{ email }}</a>
</template>
<script>
import { mapGetters } from "vuex";

export default {
 name: "SomeComponent",
 computed: {
  ...mapGetters(["email"])
}
}
</script>
```

Since, as far as I know, the `email` is not JS encoded, I could be vulnerable to XSS here, correct? Since the execution context is JS and then HTML Attribute, should I HTML attribute encode and then JS Encode? The OWASP XSS CheatSheet is not clear to me, sorry.

Comment:  interesting question  PS The `computedEmail` is redundant in your case. You can simply use `email` in the template.

Comment: @Adam Orlov: Your right :/ Will edit it now. I was just wondering about this...maybe I am over thinking it ...kinda have the feeling you're being sarcastic haha

Comment: No not at all. I am really curious  I have never though about that, but I have also never done anything serious with an Open API. My point of view on this is that if you are using API you know, done by the BE team from the company or some company you are paying for data, then you can assume they are trust worth. But if you are doing something serious with an OPEN API data, then it is good question to ask. That is why I have bookmarked it 

Comment: Ok well that answers another question of mine :D thanks for that as well. On the other hand though, how do you know that the paid API has not been compromised? I think it should be treated like any database. Yet again, one just encodes output there too.